# What is the simplest way of clearing floats in webkit?

Tags: css, webkit, css-float

I'm making a Google Chrome plugin. Therefore, the injected CSS need only work in webkit. What is the webkit-specific way of clearing floats?

By clearing floats, I mean make a parent element enclose all floating children contained within.

Comment: I don't think there is one. What are you looking for that `clear: xyz` doesn't do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline-block` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to care about the IE bugs, you can make a clearing style (for an element not to take up space) as simple as:

```
.Clear { clear: both; height: 0; }
```

as comparison, a style that takes the IE one-character-height bug into acount would be:

```
.Clear { clear: both; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

An alternative to adding a clearing tag, is to set an `overflow` style on the parent element of the floats, that will make it contin it's children. You can for example use `overflow:hidden` but without specifying a size, that way the parent will be sized by it's children.

Comment: +1 for overflow:hidden.

If you do require IE then it needs as hasLayout fix such as zoom.